# RocksDB visualization tool

Tags: database, visualization, rocksdb

I would like to know if there is any basic RocksDB visualization tool. The only one I can see is the LDB tool which is a command line.

Thanks in advance,
Hak

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Rocksdb stores data as opaque bytes - only you know how to serialize that and show it